# Function.prototype.__proto__ → Object.prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

`console.log(Function.prototype.__proto__); //Object {}`
Why not `Object.prototype?`
[KFzI3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFzI3.png)

Comment: What do yo mean by "Why not Object.prototype"? This doesn't even make sense.

Comment: `typeof(Object.prototype)` -> "object", so where dose the conclusion come from? Make sure to take time to explain the question clearly - use more words.

Comment: In which browser/user agent/host? There is no standard for how a console behaves.

Comment: Because that's how the console displays objects with non-enumerable properties. A better way to find out stuff about a value is to use `console.dir`.

Answer (score 3):

It is exactly Object.prototype.

Try this:

```
alert(Function.prototype.__proto__ === Object.prototype);
```

Comment: Or just read [ECMA-262 15.3.4](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4): "The value of the `[[Prototype]]` internal property of the Function prototype object is the standard built-in Object prototype object". :-)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can check this out in Dev tools. Go to the sources tab and under Watch Expressions section. Watch `Function` and you'll see the breakdown of the prototype chain. [More about it on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function).

Comment: @user2864740 Can you explain more?

Comment: While the ECMAScript does designate the prototype of Function objects, which provides methods like call/apply, this does not make a function object a function object. In browser implementations where the  nonstandard/deprecated `__proto__` can be modified, consider: `function x () {}; x.__proto__ = {};` After this, `x()` is still valid (the function-application operator does not use the prototype) while `x.call()` is not and `typeof x` will still report "function".

Comment: @user2864740—what "makes a Function object a Function object" might be said to be **all** of the things in [ECMA-262 13.2](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2) (for native functions), or just that it implements an internal `[[Call]]` method (e.g. callable host methods like *getElementById*).

Answer (score 0):

> Why not `Object.prototype`?

Because objects don't have "names", and the console does not know that the object you just logged is the one that is (or can be) referred to as `Object.prototype`.

Instead, it just sees that there are no enumerable properties (`{}`), and that it has a `.constructor` property which refers to a function whose [`.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) is the string `Object`.